# Can I use JSON column format to hide show power automate button?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, power-automate, json-formatting, column-formatting

Can I use JSON column format to hide show power automate button in a SharePoint list  depending if the user is an admin or not.

I don't want people with read only access to trigger the flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint JSON formatting does not support checking site/list permissions officially.

However, below JSON formatting works to check if user has read or 'more than read' permissions:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "visibility": "=if([$PermMask]>='0xb00','hidden','visible')"
  },
  "txtContent": "=if([$PermMask]>='0xb00','Read-only','More than read')"
}
```

So, you can change the visibility of power automate button element in JSON based on `[$PermMask]` as shown above.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh.Will give this a shot and let you know